# CSS not loading in Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a web page I am testing in both IE and FF. It works perfectly in IE but the style sheets will not load in Firefox.

Has anyone else experienced this type of issue with Firefox ?

Also note that this is only on my dev workstation loading the files locally...

Here is the header section of the html file:

```
<head>

<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\\server\USERS$\myID\Projects\Intranet\css\common.css">
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\\server\USERS$\myID\Projects\Intranet\css\css.css">

<title>8927.html</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Show us how you're loading in your CSS?

Comment: Could you post your HTML and describe the directory structure for the web site?

Comment: How are you including the stylesheets in your webpage? Could you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I fixed it by using the following and it now works in both IE and FF:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/common.css">
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/css.css">
```

Answer (score 4):

**UNC Paths**

If you're linking to a file in a UNC path (e.g., \\servername\share\file.ext), you will need to specify the path thusly:

```
file://///servername/share/file.ext
```

Also note that you cannot link to file://///servername to get a listing of shares at that hostname due to a bug.

Source: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work

Comment: Btw. why are you using local UNC paths to the css file? Isn't there a better solution? (like using a webserver to handle file sendings?)

Comment: This is just a staging location for HTML that ends up being moved into a production CMS.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is handled differently in Firefox than it is in IE.

However, if your css should work fine in any browser, try:

- Clearing your FF cache
- Testing in Chrome or Safari

Does your page have any code which checks for browser type that may be stopping the CSS when it detects it is FF?

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess, since I can't replicate your environment: I wonder if Firefox is having problems with either the $ in path or the backslashes. I'd first try replacing backslashes with forward slashes, then I'd try URL-encoding the $ (i.e., replacing it with %24).

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with javascript files from time to time. I think firefox is sometimes case sensitive, so make sure the path to your file and its actual name use the same capitalisation.